# On visiting a certain place, I wrote a line of poetry. Where was I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

> Longest in its kind across the globe
> Where five of seven meet the shore
> Here the rights are set in stone
> To cruise along the world's floor
>
> Where am I?

Hint 1

> The two first guesses, the Mariana Trench and the Andes, are far larger and also more well-known than this place.

Hint 2

> Shells of wisdom, in a warm basin
>  Within which lies a land of freemason

Hint 3

> This location is in the United States. The initial riddle refers to three key pieces of information: one cultural, one geographical, and one biological

Hint 4

> The phrase "set in stone" is figurative to suggest a strong value/occurrence that would be difficult to change

Hint 5

> Toward evening from the father's waters
>  With lonely monarchs and the mockers

Hint 6

> Just about all the pieces have been solved or alluded to in the comments and answers

Hint 7

> Line 2 refers to sea turtles, as identified by @user2597523
>  Hint 1: locations on a similar scale (and nearby the correct place) have been mentioned in comments and guesses
>  Hint 2: line 2 refers to Freemason Island, as identified by @user2597523 and @pandy legend
>  Hint 5: line one refers to west of the Mississippi, as identified @pandy legend
>  The "cultural" component has not been identified, but is given by lines 3 and 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you were at...

> Padre Island National Seashore in Texas.

Longest in its kind across the globe

> Padre Island is indeed the longest barrier island in the world.

Where five of seven meet the shore

> There are seven species of sea turtle, of which five are found in the Gulf of Mexico. All five have been known to nest or forage on or near the island.

Here the rights are set in stone 
To cruise along the world's floor

> This one I'm not totally sure about, but I suspect that it refers to oil drilling on the island. The oil itself is set in stone, and while there are some restrictions to protect the wildlife, it is still permitted. This is extremely harmful to the wildlife especially given that all five species of sea turtle are endangered, but it's unlikely that whoever is drilling for oil would be willing to stop anytime soon. Cruising along the world's floor could refer to the search for oil. It is also worth noting that in the United States, the "rights" (conservatives) are more likely to support oil drilling.

Shells of wisdom, in a warm basin 
Within which lies a land of freemason

> The basin refers to the Gulf of Mexico, where Padre Island (and Freemason Island) are located. Additionally, there are Big and Little Shell Beaches on the island. And finally, Shell Oil Company maintains several rigs in the Gulf of Mexico.

Toward evening from the father's waters 
With lonely monarchs and the mockers

> Monarchs and Mockers are butterflies, which migrate west along the Gulf Coast (passing Padre Island) to Mexico in autumn. 42 different species of butterfly have been sighted on the island. And of course, Padre Island is west of the Mississippi River.

Comment: Bingo! Great job. A few of your explanations were off from what I had in mind, so feel free to incorporate these. The second half referred to beach driving. In TX, beaches are public highways (you can drive on some beaches elsewhere, but in TX, they are ALL highways). The island is 60 miles long with no road. Shells of wisdom were meant to be the turtles, traditionally viewed as wise is several cultures. Finally, "with lonely monarchs and the mockers" was meant to refer to TX itself, the "lone" star state. And monarchs and mock[ingbirds] are state symbols. ("mockers" was a stretch). Great job!

Comment: Thanks! I was unfamiliar with beach driving...that clue ended up being way more literal than I expected :) I did consider that "mockers" referred to mockingbirds (especially since the mocker butterfly is found only in Africa) but, unlike monarchs, they don't migrate significantly. The "lonely" clue should have given away their relation to Texas itself—brilliant! Supremely enjoyable puzzle.

Answer (score 12):

Are you

> The Mariana Trench

Longest in its kind across the globe

> The Mariana Trench is the longest trench in the world.

Where five of seven meet the shore

> Five of the seven continents border the Pacific Ocean, where the Mariana trench is found. Europe(Russia), Asia, North America, South America, and Australia.

Here the rights are set in stone

> According to the geological traits of the Mariana Trench, the Eastern(right) tectonic plate is subducted into the Western Mariana tectonic plate. So, the right side of the trench is set into stone under the earth's crust.

To cruise along the world's floor

> The Mariana Tench is the deepest depth below sea level in the world.

Comment: You’re back!! Good to “see” you again

Comment: It looks like a perfect solution, my only doubt is that the title of the post mentions visiting the place, which is odd if the answer is correct

Comment: The "five of seven" part might be slightly mistaken. rot13(Gung Ehffvn bpphcvrf cneg bs Rhebcr qbrfa'g znxr Rhebcr obeqre gur Cnpvsvp. Vg zvtug or orggre gb ercynpr Rhebcr jvgu Nagnepgvpn, juvpu vf n gehr pbagvarag naq vf fgevpgyl nqwnprag gb gur Cnpvsvp.)

Comment: @iBug rot13(V jnf ybbxvat vagb gung, ubjrire V sbhaq gung Nagnepgvpn fgevpgyl obeqref gur Fbhgurea Bprna.  Fb, Ehffvn jnf zl orfg thrff vs V nz vaqrrq pbeerpg.)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Nope, rot13(Fbhgurea Bprna vfa'g bar bs gur 4 bprnaf pbzzbayl erpbtavmrq, juvpu ner gur Ngynagvp, Cnpvsvp, Vaqvna, naq Nepgvp.)

Comment: @iBug rot13(Nccneragyl fbzr pbhagevrf, vapyhqvat zvar, unir erpragyl erpbtavmrq gur Fbhgurea Bprna nf bar bs gur 5 znwbe bprnaf.)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Fair enough.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie this is a great guess, but not what I had in mind. I'll second BarryPoppins comment concerning traveling to this place. Generally speaking, this place is more specific then the Mariana Trench

Comment: @DanielC. Would I be any closer if I guessed on the lines of rot13(Ivetvavn Ornpu be Ybat Ornpu Pnyvsbeavn?)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie you certainly would be

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie neither of those are correct, but they are along the right lines of thought. Combine them with the suggestions from others to solve the hints and I think you'll have it before long

Comment: @DanielC. Last guess for now, but how about rot13(Purfncrnxr Onl) :)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie nope. Sorry!

Answer (score 8):

You might be at

> The [Andes Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andes)

Longest in its kind across the globe

> Longest continental mountain range in the world

Where five of seven meet the shore

> Runs through 7 South American countries: Venezuela, Colombia, Ecuador, Peru, Bolivia, Chile, and Argentina. -- Bolivia and Argentina do NOT touch the Pacific ocean side of the continent.

Here the rights are set in stone

> Maybe - On the eastern side of the range is land or the continent, where on the western side of the range is water or ocean.

To cruise along the world's floor

> Mountains are caused by the world's plates (floor) shifting/ moving.

Comment: this is a great guess, but not quite. The answer is more specific, (i.e., a lesser known location) than the Andes or Mariana Trench.

Answer (score 7):

Are you at

> Rosetta, Egypt?

> Longest in its kind across the globe

> The Rosetta Stone was found here, which was the longest translatable passage of Egyptian hieroglyphics at the time of its discovery.

> Where five of seven meet the shore

> Five of the seven wonders of the ancient world once lie on the shore of the Mediterranean Sea (The Pyramids and the Hanging Gardens of Babylon were not).

> Here the rights are set in stone

> The texts carved into the Rosetta Stone are various ancient decrees and laws

> To cruise along the world's floor

> Rosetta is at sea level, the "floor level" for the world.

> Where am I?

Hint

> The two first guesses, the Mariana Trench and the Andes, are far larger and also more well-known than this place.

> Rosetta, Egypt is a fairly obscure location, and much smaller than the two named.

Hint 2

> Shells of wisdom, in a warm basin
>  Within which lies a land of freemason

> The Mediterranean is a warm sea, with shells. The Rosetta Stone provided wisdom and insight into translating hieroglyphics. The stone is presently in the British Museum, and Great Britain is the origin of modern freemasonry.

Comment: I've been trying to make this answer work all yesterday. However, I got too fixed on rot13(Gur Avyr Qrygn univat 7 qvfgevohgnevrf va napvrag gvzrf...) You've done a better job of it than I managed, though I'm still not sure about your Hint 2 suggestion... 'Within which' makes it sound like it should be the other way round - the 'land of freemason' within 'the basin'...

Comment: I’m not convinced this is right, but it seems like it might be a step in the right direction. I really like the five of seven, so I was going around the coastline looking for things that might fit the other clues.

Comment: @Daniel great attempt! But not quite.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to guess

> Traveling on the Nile river

> Longest in its kind across the globe

> It is the longest river (disputed).
>   I understand it is also the oldest river, which would be the longest lasting.

> Where five of seven meet the shore

I can't explain this one

> Here the rights are set in stone

> Writing classically was done by carving stone.  (Egyptian Hieroglyphics)

> To cruise along the world's floor

> At the mouth, it is at sea level, which could be considered the world's floor.

Comment: Thanks for the comment David G., but it is not the Nile.

Comment: I suspected that.  My other thought was rot13(gur Zrqvgreenarna Frn), which could keep the answer to lines three and four and make line two be rot13(unf svir bs frira bs gur Jbaqref bs gur Napvrag Jbeyq), but i then can't explain line one

Answer (score 4):

Are you at

> King George Island in Antarctica?

> Longest in its kind across the globe / Where five of seven meet the shore

> King George Island is on the coastline of the Atlantic Ocean, where 5 of the 7 continents have coastline (South America, North America, Europe, Africa, and Antarctica). I think it's the longest total coastline for an ocean?

> Here the rights are set in stone / To cruise along the world's floor

> There is a monument to the Antarctic Treaty system on King George Island.

Answer (score 3):

Second Attempt

> The Great Barrier Reef

Longest in its kind across the globe

> Largest reef system in the world

Where five of seven meet the shore

> Not sure about this one - perhaps 2 continents out of 7 are separate from the others

Here the rights are set in stone

> Coral grows on submerged stones

To cruise along the world's floor

> Coral usually grows on rocks near the edges of island or continents on the ocean floor.

Hint

> Hint 2 may be leading towards unscrambling "free" to "reef" or reef building?

Comment: Thank you for the guess! But this is not correct

Answer (score 3):

2nd Try. Are you at:

> Breton National Wildlife Refuge?

> Longest in its kind across the globe

> Referring to the migration of Loggerhead sea turtles which nest there, the longest turtle migration

> Where five of seven meet the shore

> I believe that 5 of the 7 species of sea turtles have nesting sites in the US

> Here the rights are set in stone / To cruise along the world's floor

> Well the turtles are born there so I guess being born sets their right in stone to cruise the ocean floors.

> I won't explain all of your hints but I saw that you mentioned monarchs (Monarch butterflies are also famous for their migration). I could have chosen anywhere on the US southeast coast for turtle nesting but I saw that you mentioned a land of freemason, and there's actually a tiny Freemason Island near Breton National Wildlife Refuge

Comment: This is not correct, but certainly moving in the correct direction!

Answer (score 3):

Second guess!

Are you at:

> [Lake Pontchartrain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Pontchartrain), Louisiana

Longest in its kind across the globe

> [Lake Pontchartrain Causeway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Pontchartrain_Causeway) is the longest over-water bridge in the world

Where five of seven meet the shore

> Five of the seven former Confederate States, including Louisiana, meet the shore of the Gulf of Mexico

Here the rights are set in stone

> Louisiana is a red state (right wing, unlikely to change)

To cruise along the world's floor

> Unsure. Based on my other answers, this must be the "biological" reference, so could refer to wildlife such as turtles or clams which would live on the lakefloor.

Hint 2: Shells of wisdom, in a warm basin Within which lies a land of freemason

> Oysters are common in the area and are often associated with wisdom (pearls of wisdom). The warm basin could be the Gulf of Mexico. Close by there is Freemason Island, which lies within the Gulf.

Hint 5: Toward evening from the father's waters, With lonely monarchs and the mockers

> "Mississippi" means "father's water", though I would take "toward evening" as being west of there (i.e. towards sunset) whereas the lake is east of the river. Monarchs and Mockers are butterflies and [they use the bridge to cross the lake](https://journeynorth.org/tm/monarch/MigrationBridgeLA2.html)

Comment: This is not correct. But like @user2597523 this is moving in the right direction

Answer (score 3):

Third guess, mostly the same as my last answer but new location

Are you at:

> [Texas City Dyke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_City_Dike), Galveston Bay, Texas

Longest in its kind across the globe

> It is the world's longest man-made fishing pier.

Where five of seven meet the shore

> Five of the seven former Confederate States, including Texas, meet the shore of the Gulf of Mexico

Here the rights are set in stone

> Texas is a red state

To cruise along the world's floor

> Could be related to oil drilling or the fact the dyke stops the seafloor from silting up, thus allowing ships (submarines?) to pass easily. Could still be nature related too. There is a submarine on display in Seawolf Park, probably visible from the end of the pier.

Hint 2: Shells of wisdom, in a warm basin Within which lies a land of freemason

> Oysters are common in the area and are often associated with wisdom (pearls of wisdom). The warm basin could still be the Gulf of Mexico or even Galveston Bay itself. Bolivar peninsula is named after [Simón_Bolívar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sim%C3%B3n_Bol%C3%ADvar#Freemasonry) who was a Freemason.

Hint 5: Toward evening from the father's waters, With lonely monarchs and the mockers

> "Mississippi" means "father's water", "toward evening" therfore being west of there (i.e. towards sunset). Monarchs and Mockers are butterflies and I guess are also present nearby.

Comment: Close again! But no. Perhaps, working to combine guess/comments by you and others to fulfill each of the hints well

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer. I didn't want to comment and give any clues to other puzzlers.

Where am I?

> Definitely in the Amazon basin. If I had to guess: Cochabamba, Bolivia.

Longest in its kind across the globe

> The Amazon river is the longest river in the world (by some definitions)

Where five of seven meet the shore

> Five continents have their shorelines on the Atlantic Ocean, where the Amazon river empties into the sea

Here the rights are set in stone
To cruise along the world's floor

> I spent time researching this and couldn't come up with an adequate answer. Something to do with undersea rights?

Shells of wisdom, in a warm basin

> The Amazon basin restricts this to a few countries. Cochabamba, Bolivia is where one of the tributaries for the Amazon river starts. Cochabamba, very roughly, could be translated from Portuguese as 'concha' (shell) + 'bamba' (expert)

Within which lies a land of freemason

> Simon Bolivar was a famous freemason after whom Bolivia was named.

Comment: Not quite. But appreciate the effort and enjoyed this response

Answer (score 2):

Are you at:

> [The National Mall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Mall), Washington DC

Longest in its kind across the globe

> It's quite long. I can't find any reference to it being the longest in the world, but perhaps this actually refers to something other than physical length.

Where five of seven meet the shore

> As far as I can make out, there are seven memorials, of which five of them are on the shore of the [Tidal Basin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_Basin). The Jefferson Memorial, the Martin Luther King Memorial, the Franklin D. Roosevelt Memorial, the John Paul Jones Memorial and the George Mason Memorial (see below).

Here the rights are set in stone

> This could refer to many things in Washington DC. DC itself is not a state, and many things politically and legally could not be changed here.

To cruise along the world's floor

> Not sure about this one. Possibly something to do with the Reflecting pool or Tidal Basin?

Hint 2: Shells of wisdom, in a warm basin Within which lies a land of freemason

> Could again refer to the Tidal Basin, and "land of freemason" maybe doesn't refer to the Freemasons, but maybe a cryptic reference to George Mason who has a [memorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Mason_Memorial) here and was the author of the Virginia Declaration of Rights that inspired the United States Bill of Rights (so also relevant to the clues above).

Comment: I like the reasoning you've used here. However, it is not the National Mall

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Philadelphia

Longest in its kind across the globe

> longest surviving democracy in the world

Where five of seven meet the shore

> not sure, is this related to rivers or geography?

Here the rights are set in stone

> where the Declaration of Independence, Constitution, and Bill of Rights were signed/enacted

To cruise along the world's floor

> Philadelphia is at sea level

Hint 2

Shells of wisdom, in a warm basin
Within which lies a land of freemason

> Sea shells from the bay. many of the countries founders were freemasons

Hint 3

This location is in the United States. The initial riddle refers to three key pieces of information: one cultural, one geographical, and one biological

> cultural -> democracy,bill of rights 
>  geographical ->rivers?
>  biological -> I have no idea

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but this is not correct

Answer (score 1):

I can't make this answer work for all the clues, so it's unlikely to be correct. However, I found out some interesting facts, so I thought I would share it.

Could it be:

> Utah?

**Clues that match with the answer**

Longest in its kind across the globe:

> I can't find anything that is the 'longest', but '[Pando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pando_(tree))' in the Fishlake National Forest is the heaviest organism in the world. This could be the biological clue.

> Alternatively, if we interpret 'across the globe' literally, the [Great Salt Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Salt_Lake) is the largest salt water lake in the Western Hemisphere, according to Wikipedia - that is, across the globe from the large lakes in the Eastern Hemisphere (lake Aral, Caspian sea...). This would be the geographical clue.

The rights are set in stone:

> One of the hints talks about something difficult to change, and Utah is a Red state ('right' would be intended as 'political right').

Warm basin:

> Utah lies in the [Great Basin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Basin) area

Land of freemason:

> Interesting entry about the influence of [freemasonry in early Mormonism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mormonism_and_Freemasonry)

I know this covers only a fraction of the clues, but as I said I thought it would be interesting.

Comment: As you suspected, this is not correct. But your interpretation of "the rights are set in stone" is among the closer of the attempts so far

Answer (score 1):

Are you the:

> [Grand Canyon?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Canyon)

Longest in its kind across the globe

> This canyon is one of the longest in the world.

Where five of seven meet the shore

> The Grand Canyon is one of the seven natural wonders of the world ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonders_of_the_World#Seven_Natural_Wonders_of_the_World)). Only Mount Everest and the Parícutin volcano do not meet the shore, and the others do (the polar auroras meet the Arctic/Antarctic oceans, the shores of the Grand Canyon meet the Colorado River, and Victoria Falls is a waterfall).

Here the rights are set in stone

> The area surrounding the canyon has been protected for a long time: the Grand Canyon National Park celebrated its 100th anniversary in 2019, and the Navajo Nation, where one part is inside the Grand Canyon, has been established since 1868.

To cruise along the world's floor

> The canyon is one of the deepest in the world, but it is not the deepest (for example, the Yarlung Tsangpo Grand Canyon).

Regarding the hints:

> Hint 1: The Grand Canyon while still large, is only 446 km long, compared to the 2,500 km long Mariana Trench, and the Andes which is even longer still.

> Hint 2: The Grand Canyon is located in the Colorado River basin (which is in the middle of the desert, hence the 'warm basin'). The Grand Canyon is in Arizona however, so no connection to freemasons.

Comment: Thanks for your guess! But I was not at the Grand Canyon

Answer (score 1):

OK I'm reaching here, but are you at:

> The Maritime Pilots Institute?

It's in the New Orleans area where previous answers seem to point, and I believe they teach about piloting ships through the Panama Canal, which would fit:

> Here the rights are set in stone /
> To cruise along the world's floor

Comment: Thanks for the guess! But this is not correct